# Solving a second-order nonlinear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

May I ask for any solutions/ hints to solve the following (general) second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation?

$$\frac{d^2 f(y)}{d y^2} + \frac{\lambda}{f(y)} = 0$$ for $\lambda$ is a constant.

I thought about using the substitution $h(y) = \frac{1}{f(y)}$ to obtain
$$h\frac{d^2h}{dy^2} - 2\left(\frac{dh}{dy}\right)^2 - \lambda h^4 = 0$$.

EDIT: From the comments, of which I'm very grateful for, I got

$$2\frac{df}{dy} \frac{d^2 f(y)}{d y^2} + 2\lambda \frac{df}{dy}\frac{1}{f(y)} = 0$$
which is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{df}{dy}\right)^2 + 2\lambda ln(f) = c$$ where c is a constant. Therefore

$$f(y) = e^{\frac{1}{2\lambda} \left[c - \left(\frac{df}{dy}\right)^2\right]}$$ which is implicit? Am I able to proceed further?

Thank you.

Comment: Multiply by $2f'(y)$ and integrate.

Comment: Maybe multiply both sides by $f’$ and integrate once? Haven’t tried it myself but it looks promising. Added: Looks like @StartWearingPurple beat me to it! 

Comment: I get $\left(\frac{df}{dy}\right)^2 + 2\lambda \ln(f) = c$ where c is a constant. Am I able to go further?

Comment: Your equation is now separable: solve for $f',$ then bring all of the $f$ terms to the left-hand side and integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Stephen Donovan's comment:

If we subtract and take a square root, we have $$\frac{df}{dy}=\pm\sqrt{c-2\lambda\ln{(f)}}$$  Rearranging, $$\frac{df}{\sqrt{c-2\lambda\ln{(f)}}}=\pm dy$$ which is autonomous and so can be solved in quadratures.

Do those quadratures have a nice closed-form solution?  No.

Ironically, the easiest way to see this is that the integrals *do* admit a further simplification.  Let $$u=\sqrt{c-2\lambda\ln{(f)}}\Leftrightarrow f=e^{\frac{c-u^2}{2\lambda}}$$  Then $$df=e^{\frac{c-u^2}{2\lambda}}\cdot\left(-\frac{u\,du}{\lambda}\right)$$ so that $$\pm\lambda\,dy=e^{\frac{c-u^2}{2\lambda}}\,du$$

Thus your differential equation is solved by the Gaussian CDF (up to constants/linear shifts).